# Dispatch touch outside the Dialog/Alert

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

I am trying to show a popup whenever user gets on a call, much like truecaller app. The popup will show various info about the other party.

I have implemented everything in it, except the popup UI.
I have first tried with calling a simple activity which shows on just top half of the screen, leaving bottom half as transparent.
Then I tried with a dialog activity, which shows the popup on center of the screen while I want it on top.
Lastly I have tried with System Alerts.

In all three scenario My popup was on certain part of the screen and rest of the screen was transparent. 
However the touch even doesn't pass from the transparent area to the activity/UI behind it. I want the popup to appear till the user is on call which I did using a timer to call the popup activity after two seconds of getting the call.
The problem is I want the user to interact with rest of the screen even if the popup is shown, but I am unable to do it in all three solutions. The user can't hang up the call and can't even do anything else till the popup is shown.

So my question is, is there any way I can show the popup on top half of the screen while the rest half still pass touch events to the rest of the System UI, just like how truecaller popup does (or how toast messages does)?

Here's the two system alert code I tried -

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED,
                PixelFormat.OPAQUE);
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
windowManager.addView(preRootView, params);
```

and

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT |
                LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                        LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
windowManager.addView(preRootView, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't find answer yet, but looks like there's libraries which allows you to create floating windows without intercepting all the touch events on transparent areas.

I am trying [Standout library](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut) and it's working great. I am also looking towards trying [Tooleap](http://www.tooleap.com/) library too.

I haven't yet read the source code of Standout, so can't say how they did it.